# Issue with Snowflake Group by condition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by seq8(1))  as unique_id,
    ContractVersionId,
    Origin,
    LISTAGG(FIRSTSTATION , '|| ') within group (ORDER BY FIRSTSTATION) AS InterTransptAndCarrCode
    FROM LdCONTRACTMULTISEGMENT
    WHERE firstsegair1='AC' AND secondsegair1 <> 'AC'
    GROUP BY 1,2,SECONDSEGAIR1;
```

Edit: This is the table create

```
CREATE TABLE VIKRAMG.LDCONTRACTMULTISEGMENT 
( CONTRACTVERSIONID INTEGER, ORIGIN CHAR(3) , FIRSTSTATION CHAR(3) , FIRSTSEGAIR1 CHAR(3) , SECONDSTATION CHAR(3) , SECONDSEGAIR1 CHAR(3) , THIRDSTATION CHAR(3) , THIRDSEGAIR1 CHAR(3) ) ;
```

Getting this error.

> Window function [ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ8(1) ASC NULLS LAST)]
> appears outside of SELECT, QUALIFY, and ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: Can you post what the issue you are facing with relevant sample data and steps / details?

Comment: Getting the this error.  Window function [ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ8(1) ASC NULLS LAST)] appears outside of SELECT, QUALIFY, and ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: This is the table we need to create it Snowflake.                                                                           CREATE  TABLE VIKRAMG.LDCONTRACTMULTISEGMENT 
(
      CONTRACTVERSIONID INTEGER,
      ORIGIN CHAR(3) ,
      FIRSTSTATION CHAR(3) ,
      FIRSTSEGAIR1 CHAR(3) ,
      SECONDSTATION CHAR(3) ,
      SECONDSEGAIR1 CHAR(3) ,
      THIRDSTATION CHAR(3) ,
      THIRDSEGAIR1 CHAR(3) )
;

Comment: I ran your create, and had the query working just by explicitly naming columns in the GROUP BY. `GROUP BY CONTRACTVERSIONID,ORIGIN,SECONDSEGAIR1;`
I did not see the same error that you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Your query contains `GROUP BY` twice, the list of columns to group by contains a column that is not present in the list of selected columns and most of the query is commented out.

The following query fixes those 3 problems and might work, but we can't know without sample data.

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by seq8(1)) as unique_id, ContractVersionId, Origin FROM """ + self.params.TD_STG_DB_NM + """.LdCONTRACTMULTISEGMENT WHERE firstsegair1='AC' AND secondsegair1 <> 'AC' GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: Above query is not working, can you please try with above comments